# How do I define a string in formal language by means of a definition of tuple?

Tags: definition, formal-languages

I'm constructing mathematical notions and definition from the bottom of the mathematical structure. So whenever I learn, or encounter new concepts, I try to define it step by step, without using any informally premised concepts, even if they look obvious (except primitive notions, of course.).

*String* in formal language is, informally speaking, a juxtaposition of finitely many symbols. I think, to define this term rigorously, we have to define *order* first. And I already defined *ordered pair*, or generally *tuple* which contains a concept of *order*. Roughly speaking, we can define an ordered pair by only adopting set-element concept, $(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$. I think this definition is the most foundational way to define *order*.
So I tried to define *string* by means of this concept, but having problem as I already defined tuple. How do I define *string* in a very foundational way?

Comment: can't you do the same thing? $(a,b,c)=\{a,\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: @Bananarama I don't get your point. Of course I can do the same thing and also can generalize to n-tuple. BTW, your definition is wrong, if we use inductive way.

Comment: Wait, is it just ok to think string as tuple? For example, can we think a string $math$ as $(m,a,t,h)$? Should I define $string$ $notation$, which removes every commas and parentheses? Oh wait, isn't it so called $polish$ $notation$?

Comment: Is polish notation of a tuple is a string?!

Comment: @novice, I don't know, I'm merely giving my opinion, take a chill pill.

Answer (score 1):

A *word* $w$ in the context of formal languages and automata theory is a sequence of symbols from an alphabet $\Sigma$

$$
w \in \Sigma^I = \{ \varphi : I \to \Sigma \}
$$

for some index set $I$.

The usual set theoretic modeling for sequences and maps apply.

Symbol and alphabet are just different names for element and non-empty set.

A set of words is called a language.

The length of a word is $|w| = \mbox{card}(I)$.

A special word is $\varepsilon$ the word of length $0$, the empty word.
It is the neutral element of the concatenation operation

$$
\cdot : \Sigma^* \times \Sigma^* \to  \Sigma^* \\
\cdot(u,v) = uv
$$

with $|uv| = |u| + |v|$ and $uv$ having the first $|u|$ sequence elements like $u$ and the remaining $|v|$ like $v$,
where I used the set of finite words $\Sigma^*$

$$
\Sigma^* = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} \Sigma^n
$$

where $\Sigma^n$ is the set of words of length $n$ over $\Sigma$,
while one can define infinite words as well (see 
[Büchi automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton)).

See [Free Monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid) for a more algebraic perspective.